# Spark Structured Streaming - Customer Sink worked in Spark 2.2.0 but gets exception in Spark 2.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Recently we migrated our project from Spark 2.2.0 cloudera2 to Spark 2.3.0 cloudera2 and noticed some customer Sinks which used to work but now failed with exceptions.  To make it simple, I rewrote a tiny case so that helpers can copy and paste the code to test it.

```
package question

import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._

class NCSink extends Sink {
    def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {
        data.foreachPartition { iterator =>
            val socket = new Socket("localhost", 7778)
            val writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream, true)
            iterator.foreach(row => writer.println(row.getString(0)))
            socket.close
        }
    }
}

class NCSinkProvider extends StreamSinkProvider {
    def createSink(sc: SQLContext, params: Map[String, String], columns: Seq[String], mode: OutputMode): Sink = new NCSink()
}

object NCStreaming {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
        import spark.implicits._
        spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 7777).load.as[String].writeStream.format("question.NCSinkProvider").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint").start.awaitTermination
    }
}
```

The above program can be run in Spark 2.2.0 (deployed by cloudera2 parcel)

Sent

```
[johnlin@localhost ~]$ nc -lk 7777
good
better
best
never
let
it
rest
```

Received

```
[johnlin@localhost ~]$ nc -lk 7778
good
better
never
it
let
rest
best
```

However in Spark 2.3.0 (deployed by cloudera2 parcel) it gets an exception `Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
LogicalRDD [value#6], true

=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 072fce9e-0cc5-482b-a971-17102da37528, runId = 415272e9-2c2a-47de-947e-fbf64c8cc0da]
Current Committed Offsets: {TextSocketSource[host: localhost, port: 7777]: 12}
Current Available Offsets: {TextSocketSource[host: localhost, port: 7777]: 13}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
TextSocketSource[host: localhost, port: 7777]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
LogicalRDD [value#6], true

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2674)
        at question.NCSink.addBatch(NCStreaming.scala:12)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:474)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
        ... 1 more
```

I searched on this exception to know that it might be related to using an unsupported operation such as multiple aggregations.  But I don't know how to find it out from the query plan in the error message.
I know Spark 2.3 structured streaming introduced some new features.  But I cannot figure out what modifications to my code are needed.  Could you help me?

Comment: I tried to tag "apache-spark-2.3" but had not enough privilege

Comment: I dig into Spark's source code and found a piece of code.  If I modify `data.foreachPartition { iterator =>` into 
`data.queryExecution.toRdd.foreachPartition { iterator =>` then it works in both Spark 2.2 and Spark 2.3

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believe is the two branches will be created for the logical plan  for this, but you are calling `start` on the second branch, leaving the first one unhandled, so maybe with Spark 2.3.0, they have fixed it to be explicitly handled.

```
spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 7777).load.as[String]
     .writeStream.format("question.NCSinkProvider").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
     .start
     .awaitTermination
```

This is purely my assumption and I could be wrong but can you try this one?

```
object NCStreaming {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
        import spark.implicits._
        val data = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 7777).load.as[String]
        val query = data.writeStream.format("question.NCSinkProvider").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint").start()
        query.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've seen similar answer and tested before I posted this question.  OK, I tried again just now.  It threw the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I dig into spark's source code to study what has changed.  I found if I modify

```
    data.foreachPartition { iterator =>
```

into

```
    data.queryExecution.toRdd.foreachPartition { iterator =>
```

then it can work correctly.

Moreover, I realized that since spark 2.0.0, I could use ForeachWriter for this kind of output streaming.

```
package question

import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket
import org.apache.spark.sql._

class NCWriter(host: String, port: Int) extends ForeachWriter[String] {
    var socket: Socket = _
    var writer: PrintWriter = _

    def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
        socket = new Socket(host, port)
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream, true)
        true
    }

    def process(record: String): Unit = writer.println(record)

    def close(exception: Throwable): Unit = socket.close
}

object NCStreaming {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
        import spark.implicits._
        spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 7777).load.as[String].writeStream.foreach(new NCWriter("localhost", 7778)).outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint").start.awaitTermination
    }
}
```